# How to get my display on my textView in android?

Tags: java, android

So I am developing android program which displays my age given their birth year.But my app does not show any answer it just shows 0 when button in pressed.
Can you please suggest where I am going wrong.And tell me how to display difference between 2017 - myAge.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 Button press;
EditText editText;
TextView enterText;
int  myAge;
int yearOfBirth;
int year = 2017;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText) ;
     enterText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.entertext);
     press = (Button)findViewById(R.id.press);

       try
         {
          yearOfBirth = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

           }catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }



             press.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  myAge = yearOfBirth;
                  enterText.setText(String.valueOf(myAge));
              }
          });
   }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You should get the value of the edittext from within your click listener. Currently you're getting the value of the edit text when your app starts (onCreate). If you want to get the value of the edit text when you press a button you need to put in in the onClickListener

Comment: And to get correct output subtract `year` from `yearOfBirth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove

```
yearOfBirth = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
```

in the try block and add it inside the onClick block.

and instead of

```
myAge = yearOfBirth;
```

write

```
int currYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
myAge = currYear - yearOfBirth;
```

putting year = 2017 will only work for this year that is why I suggest you to use Calendar class which gives you the exact year.

Comment: Thank you so much the code works like charm.I am new to android and this helps me to learn new things quickly .thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're just missing a step of calculating the age.

You're fetching the `yearOfBirth` correctly, but you're just setting `myAge` to it, not doing something like

```
myAge = year - yearOfBirth
```

Like this.

```
press.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  myAge = year - yearOfBirth; // Here.
                  enterText.setText(String.valueOf(myAge));
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your logic for calculating age is wrong.

```
myAge = year - yearOfBirth; //calculate age
```

This should work.